# How do you avoid Stroll or TiddlyWiki listing images as orphans when you transclude them?

Tags: tiddlywiki

I'm using **Stroll**, a variant of **TiddlyWiki** that imitates **Roam Research** (more or less).

I'm a heavy image user, so I have a lot of image tiddlers linked to an external directory via canonical uris.

I want to use these images in other tiddlers filled with text, to comment them, to use them to illustrate a point, etc.

The problem is that when I *transclude* the image tiddlers (via double curly brackets), they still appear as orphans. This is an undesirable behaviour in my case. If I have used an image at least once, I don't want it to appear as an orphan.

The solution I have found is awkward: I transclude the image via double curly brackets, and inmediately below I write a link to the image (via double square brackets, as is the norm in Stroll and RoamResearch), so it doesn't appear as an orphan.

So in the editor mode, I write this:

{{PhaistosDisc.jpg}}

[[PhaistosDisc.jpg]]

That is double work and it leaves an undesired link below the image in the Viewing mode.

Another failed solution: if you try to modify the system tiddler that manages orphans ($:/core/Filters/Orphans) and modify it like this...

[all[orphans]!has[_canonical_uri]sort[title]]

... then the image tiddlers that really ARE orphans (they have never been linked OR transcluded) dissapear from the orphans list, and that is undesirable too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately TiddlyWiki currently doesn't keep track of where tiddlers are transcluded, so I don't think this is possible. There is an [open PR](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5/pull/4766) related to this.